# Autorun a video on a USB drive running a portable copy of VLC

Tags: usb, video, vlc-media-player, autorun, portable-apps

I have been working on a film project for a customer who wants me to deliver the content to his clients (all using Windows) on a number of USB drives.

He wants me to set up the drive in such a way that when it is plugged in, the content will automatically play on the client's computer.

I mentioned to him that not every client will have the right media player or codecs to view the content, and that if each client had VLC Media Player that would work best.

What I'm wondering is, is there a way to include a portable copy of VLC Media Player on the USB, and upon inserting the drive into the computer, the content will play using the portable copy of VLC.

If this is possible, could the people answering this question include details on how to set this up, and auto-run scripts if necessary.

Many thanks for any help on this.

Comment: Will they all even be running the same platform? 'Film project' almost implies a higher number of Macs than 'normal'. You cannot do this automatically on a Mac - the security simply will not let you. idk for Windows; I'd imagine a lot of people have auto-run switched off for the same reasons, security.

Comment: No, all his clients will be using Windows. Please take this as perfectly accurate and not in the respect that _"well one of them will definitely have a mac"_.

Comment: Sorry, can't help on Windows. I haven't allowed any Win machine in the building to have auto-run on in 15 years.

Comment: His clients are not technical people. If they have auto-run disabled, I would be extremely surprised, and I would also deliver the media in some other way to them.

Comment: I'd deliver it on Vimeo.. or similar. That's pretty hard to get wrong :/

Comment: Good thought, I would use Wistia for such a project, but I'll leave the question standing, as his clients are paying for this media, and if the link gets shared, it would be compromised.

Comment: Media is pretty 'shareable' these days, whatever it starts on. Give them a backup on USB, but make the main presentation online. Two birds, one stone, no auto-play.

Comment: I'm delivering the content in a VCD format on a USB, hardly shareable except by technically minded people who want to go out of their way to do so. The question still stands.

Comment: I'll suggest mpv over vlc, but is autorun expected to be reliable anyway?

Comment: "Autorun on USB/Removable devices has been turned off in Windows since April 2009."

Comment: [Bypass disabled autorun for USB devices on Windows 7](//superuser.com/q/538153)

Comment: [How to Make Windows Autorun USB Flash Drives](https://www.raymond.cc/blog/how-to-make-windows-autorun-usb-flash-drives/)